# Echo different languages from php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can solve my PHP web page file language encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516589/how-i-can-solve-my-php-web-page-file-language-encoding)

I have different langaues data in database(mysql).But when I select and echo a data in html page it will show as question marks"????"  Why is that? How can I overcome this?

Comment: you should everything(html, database, connection to database froom any lang) in one encoding (e.g UTF-8)

Comment: This question is asked daily here. Search is your friend.

Comment: I*'m out of votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516589/how-i-can-solve-my-php-web-page-file-language-encoding

Answer (score 0):

It could be a character encoding problem. Which character encoding are you using and which one your is browser using?

There is a similar topic discussed here so you can also check it: [How I can solve my PHP web page file language encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516589/how-i-can-solve-my-php-web-page-file-language-encoding)

Comment: its utf8_general_ci how can I set it for the browser?

Comment: Are you sending this as content header? Please check the question in the link I gave you. He shows how to set headers in PHP. And also always try to use UTF-8.

Comment: Im not using any headers..just load from the database and diplay

Comment: As I am telling you use "UTF-8" and then use `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")` then you should be good. Don't forget to check the char-set in DB too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your html-page is using a different character encoding as your mysql. Make sure to convert your text to the correct character encoding.

EDIT: Knowing now that your database uses utf8 encoding then another possibility is that the text you inserted in your database is not compatible with the utf8 encoding. So either encode the inserting data to utf8 or change both html page and database to ISO-8859-1 encoding (which is usually the correct one).

Comment: my database is using utf8_general_ci.But how can I set same encoding to the page? <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> doesnt work??

Comment: I've edited my answer with another possibility where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the head section of the HTML page use the appropriate charset declaration like e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I Added this..But not working

Comment: Probably the data are coded in another charset than "UTF-8". This is a per document/page setting, all data in the page must conform to the declared charset.