# Use php DOMDocument() to get multipule span tag values and insert them into mysql db

Tags: php, domdocument

I need get multiple values from span tags using php, for example :

```
   <div>
    <span class='name'>name value</span>
    <span class='city'>city name</span>
    <span class='street'>street name</span>
    <span class='phone'>+17240000000</span>
    </div>
  <div>
   <span class='name'>name value 2</span>
   <span class='city'>city name 2</span>
   <span class='street'>street name 2</span>
   <span class='phone'>+17240000000 2</span>
  </div>
```

I have to get span values using span class, i try this code to get the value, and it's working put for just 1 value such as "name" :

```
<?
$html = "<div>
         <span class='name'>name value</span>
         <span class='city'>city name</span>
         <span class='street'>street name</span>
         <span class='phone'>+17240000000</span>
         </div>
         <div>
         <span class='name'>name value 2</span>
         <span class='city'>city name 2</span>
         <span class='street'>street name 2</span>
         <span class='phone'>+17240000000 2</span>
         </div>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$entries = $dom_xpath->evaluate("//span[@class='name']");
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
   echo  $entry->nodeValue."<br />";
}
?>
```

Is there anyone to help me to retouch the code so i can get all values

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
......
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span){
  echo $span->nodeValue . '<br>';
  //echo $span->getAttribute('class');
}
```

Base on the above format you may want to try this (assuming that the className will never change and always present)

```
......
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$result = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
    $temp = array();
    foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span){
        $temp[$span->getAttribute('class')] = $span->nodeValue; 
    }

    // db insert here
    // You may want to do some error check before inserting the data by making sure the array key exist 
    // need to escape data (SQL_injection)
    //mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (`name`,`city`,`street`,`phone`) VALUES('{$temp['name']}','{$temp['city']}','{$temp['street']}','{$temp['phone']}')");

    $result[] = $temp;

}

print_r($result);
```

You need to escape you values before inserting them into db (sql injection) and a more efficient want of doing bulk insert --
Read more at [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

**OR**

```
 $entries = $dom_xpath->evaluate("//span[@class='name']")
```

to

```
 $entries = $dom_xpath->evaluate("//span")
```

Comment: looks good, but can I put it in the variable. such $name = entry[1]; and $phone=$entry[2]; this is just example so i can insert them in the database

Comment: Take a look at my update code... I am not too sure what you are trying to accomplish because you are going to have a issue with have 2 'name', 'city' etc. What you may want to do is do a 2 dimension array and get the value div by div ... arr[0][name] ... arr[1][name]

Comment: thank you for fast replay, i want to insert name,city,street,phone into database. so when i put it in foreach the data will be insert one by one. sorry for my English and thanks again. 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (name,city,street,phone) VALUES('$name','$city','$street','$phone')")

Comment: Take a look at the code above...it should work the way you want now

Comment: You may want to do some error check before inserting the data by making sure the array key exist

Comment: everything is OK with insert the data, but i have some problem with charset encoding. i want to insert the data with chrset=windows-1256,because the data unreadable right now

Comment: i found it, its : mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516589/how-i-can-solve-my-php-web-page-file-language-encoding.. plus mysql_real_escape_string should help