# Using php and odbc connection, not getting result from SQL with é in query?

Tags: php, sql, encoding, odbc

I have php page querying from a SQL database in the following manner:

```
$virtual_dsn = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydatabase';
$connection = odbc_connect($virtual_dsn,user,pass) or die('ODBC Error:: '.odbc_error().' :: '.odbc_errormsg().' :: '.$virtual_dsn);
odbc_exec($connection,mydatabase);

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné'";
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
```

I know that there are rows in the table that should match this query but they are not being returned.  I have narrowed the problem down to the "é" character; i.e. queries without that character return as expected but I am not able to query records that contain "é".  I suspect the problem has something to do with the ecoding of the characters.  I hoped there was some way to specify what characterset should be used for my ODBC connection or query.  If there is I cannot find it.

What am I missing.  Thanks.

Comment: check this: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/7308476/206502>

Comment: If this is your real code, the quoting is invalid: `$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné';`  Surround the query string in double quotes.

Comment: I corrected type in question.  That was not the issue.  The code works with queries except for ones with "é".

Answer (score 0):

Missing qouta. I rewrite your line.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné'";`

Comment: That was a typo in the question.

Comment: Ok, then.. you have a chars problem: in console: SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'; or.. in query use: COLLATE utf8_bin after where condition, sorry but i don't know what si the best charset for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Crsr but no luck so far.  in the sql database the collation for the table is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I tried: $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné' COLLATE utf8_bin"; and $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné' COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"; and $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = 'Séjourné' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"; None of which worked.

Comment: view my answer.. it was a lot of code to write in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do this:

```
create table test1 (
title text)
default charset = utf8, default collate = utf8_general_ci;
insert into test1 values ('tèst');
insert into test1 values ('tèst');
insert into test1 values ('tèst');
insert into test1 values ('tèst');
insert into test1 values ('tèst');
insert into test1 values ('test');
insert into test1 values ('test');
insert into test1 values ('test');
insert into test1 values ('test');
```

and run this queries:

```
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE title = 'tèst'
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE title = 'test'
```

What are your results?  For me, in both cases, return all of records.

LE:

```
odbc_exec($connection, "SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
odbc_exec($connection, "SET client_encoding='UTF-8'");
```

or utf8_general_ci

It is necessary that the results need to be different depending è character?